# How to represent it with UNIQUE indexes and foreign keys?

Tags: foreign-key, database-design

"Group" is a group of pupils. "Topic" is a topic of lessons.

To every group corresponds exactly one topic. (So there may be multiple groups per topic.)

To a pupil corresponds multiple groups, but maximum one group per topic.

How to implement this in terms of UNIQUE indexes and foreign keys in MySQL?

Comment: A group can have many students and a student can belong to many groups?

Comment: Yes, a group can have many students and a student can belong to many groups

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a common problem. The "trick" is to:

- add in `Groups` - besides the Primary Key - a redundant Unique constraint on `(Topic, Group)`.
- this allows you to add the `Topic` attribute in the `Participates` relation and
- forces you to modify the Foreign Key constraint from `Participates` to `Groups` so it includes `Topic`, not only `Group`.
- then you can add a Unique constraint on `Participates (Pupil, Topic)` (meaning a pupil can participate only once in a topic, not twice or more, which is the wanted result.)

  ```
  Topics
    Topic  PK

  Lessons
    Lesson PK 
    Topic         FK -> Topics

  Groups
    Group  PK UQ1
    Topic     UQ1 FK -> Topics  

  Pupils
    Pupil  PK

  PupilParticipatesInGroup
    Pupil  PK UQ1 FK1 -> Pupils
    Group  PK     FK2 -> Groups
    Topic     UQ1 FK2
  ```

Appendix

```
 Abbreviation   Constraint
 ------------   -----------
   PK           Primary Key
   UQ           Unique 
   FK           Foreign Key
```

Note that the design is in **[`3NF`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form)** and that the redundant Unique constraint on `Topics` is only needed for the implementation in most DBMS (so the Foreign Key is enforced.)

The only other issue is the `Group -> Topic` dependency in the `Participates` relation which makes the schema to violate **[`BCNF`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form)**.

In the linked page, in paragraph [Achievability of BCNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form#Achievability_of_BCNF), you'll see that it has been proven that not all tables can be decomposed into tables that satisfy `BCNF` and preserve the dependencies that held in the original table. The provided example is striking similar to the `Participates` table here:

> In some cases, a non-BCNF table cannot be decomposed into tables that satisfy BCNF and preserve the dependencies that held in the original table. Beeri and Bernstein showed in 1979 that, for example, a set of functional dependencies `{AB → C, C → B}` cannot be represented by a BCNF schema.[6] Thus, *unlike the first three normal forms, **BCNF is not always achievable.***

Lets make one more change nonetheless, in order to remedy that (if we can!):

---

Lets examine what happens if we remove (as if it never existed) the `Primary Key (Group)` constraint from `Groups` (and put the Unique in its place.) Lets also change the Primary key in `Participates` - notice - to be exactly the Unique constraint that is our target from the beginning. The design becomes (first two tables omitted as they remain intact):

```
    Groups
      Group  PK 
      Topic  PK     FK -> Topics  

    Pupils
      Pupil  PK

    PupilParticipatesInGroup
      Pupil  PK     FK1 -> Pupils
      Group         FK2 -> Groups
      Topic  PK     FK2
```

No redundant columns at all. Magic! The `Participates` is a common many-to-many relation between `Groups` and `Pupils` (as our model wants) and the two Foreign Keys are referencing the Primary Keys of the corresponding tables.

So, what happened? *Magic?* (not really, no) And isn't the `Group` still a candidate key in `Groups`? (removing it was only a thought experiment anyway.) Don't we lose something by omitting this constraint from the actual tables?

---

The issue - and why the above is solving it - is that the Unique constraint you are trying to model **needs** the `Topic` attribute in the `Participates` relation. So, you have to use a candidate key in `Groups` which is compound and includes `Topic`. It doesn't necessarily have to be `(Topic, Group)`. It could be some other combination. What other attributes does `Groups` have?

If, for example, there is an attribute `OrderNo` in `Groups` and `(Topic, OrderNo`) is unique, then we could have this design (at last!) where there is no redundancy, no superfluous attributes, all constraints are there and the schema is in `BCNF`:

```
    Groups
      Group   PK 
      Topic      UQ1 FK -> Topics
      OrderNo    UQ1

    Pupils
      Pupil   PK

    PupilParticipatesInGroup
      Pupil   PK     FK1 -> Pupils
      Topic   PK     FK2 -> Groups
      OrderNo        FK2
```

Comment: 1. I don't understand your notation. 2. `Topic` in `PupilParticipatesInGroup` seems superfluous because the topic is unambiguously determined by a group

Comment: Your solution requires me to add redundant `Topic` field to the `PupilParticipatesInGroup` table. For having no superfluous fields, isn't it better to use transactions instead of UNIQUE indexes and FKeys?

Comment: Using transactions is good yes. But that doesn't mean you can remove Primary, Unique and Foreign key constraints. Who is going to take care of the integrity then? The transactions? How?

Comment: Can your solution be modified not to add superfluous PupilParticipatesInGroup.Topic field?