# Data inconsistency prohibition if a table refers to another via two many-to-many relationships

Tags: database-design, foreign-key, constraint, consistency

I have following database design (by `=>` foreign key constraints are depicted):

```
Company[id]
CompanyRealm[id, company_id=>Company.id]many2many

Project[id, company_id=>Company.id]
ProjectRealm[id, project_id=>Project.id, company_realm_id=>CompanyRealm.id]many2many
```

Problem is that provided database design allows inconsistent data. For example:

```
Company1(id=1)
Company2(id=2)
CompanyRealm(id=11, company_id=1)
Project(id=33, company_id=2)
ProjectRealm(id=44, project_id=33, company_realm_id=11)
```

(`Company` can have many `Realms`, `Project` belong to `Company` and  may concern any number of company's `Realms`)

ProjectRealm refers to two different companies:

- Company1 (via CompanyRealm); and
- Company2 (via Project).

Is something wrong with my DB design?
If yes - which prescriptions are violated?
If no - how to prevent incorrect data insertion (via constraint? trigger with exception?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right, the design allows inconsistencies, exactly what you notice. A `ProjectRealm` may be referring through `Project` to a company and through `CompanyRealm` to another company.

This is not uncommon, it appears when there is a triangular or a "diamond" shape in the relationships:

```
Realm          Company
   \           /     \
    \         /       \
     \       /         \
    CompanyRealm     Project
             \         /
              \       /  
               \     /    
             ProjectRealm
```

The common solution, if you want to enforce this via DRI (Declarative Referential Integrity), ie. through usual `UNIQUE`, `FOREIGN KEY` and `CHECK` constraints - and not though triggers - is to use composite keys for the `ProjectRealm REFERENCES CompanyRealm` and for the `ProjectRealm REFERENCES Project` foreign keys.

You will need to replace the `company_realm_id` with 2 columns (`company_id`, `realm_id`) and add a composite `UNIQUE` constraint on each of the two referenced tables (or modify their `PRIMARY KEY`):

```
Company [id]

Realm [id]

CompanyRealm [id, realm_id=>Realm.id, company_id=>Company.id,
              UNIQUE(company_id, realm_id)]

Project [id, company_id=>Company.id,
         UNIQUE(company_id, id)]

ProjectRealm [id, project_id, company_id, realm_id,
              (company_id, project_id) => Project (company_id, id),
              (company_id, realm_id) => CompanyRealm (company_id, realm_id)]
```

See also several other questions, where the same (or quite similar) problem appears. The diamond pattern is obvious in all:

- [Best data modelling approach to handle redundant foreign keys in relational model](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120246/best-data-modeling-approch-to-handle-redundant-foreign-keys-in-relational-model)
  and the nice answer and logical models and diagrams by MDCCL.
- [Foreign Key Constraint over two tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109060/foreign-key-constraint-over-two-tables)
- [How to represent it with UNIQUE indexes and foreign keys?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45744/how-to-represent-it-with-unique-indexes-and-foreign-keys)
- [Many to Many and Weak Entities](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34040/many-to-many-and-weak-entities)
- [Constrains relationship](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49513/constrains-relationship)

Comment: Thanks. In your solution tables looks like containing `redundant` data. In my opinion it is better than allowing inconsistent data. But in the name of art: are you solution violate some of NF?

Comment: No, if I am not wrong, they are 3NF, probably 5NF as well. It seems like the `company_id` is redundant in the `ProjectRealm`, true. In a way it is but since it's part of a `UNIQUE` key (`(project_id, company_id, realm_id)` is unique I assume) it doesn't violate any NF. I think I have discussed this is another question extensively, let me find the link. By the way, I would remove the `CompanyRealm (id)` and the `ProjectRealm (id)` if it was my design, unless they are there for specific, performance issues, with the DBMS you plan to implement this in.