# MySQL Double many-to-many on an Entity

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a project where I have **Products** and **SKU's**. Each Product has one or many SKU's.

I also have **Shops** that can have many to many Products, So a Product can belong to multiple Shops and a Shop can have multiple Products.

To finish, each Shop can choose which SKU's they want for which Products.
So I as a Shop can choose to sell the Tshirt White, which may have (XS,S,M,L) and I can choose (XS,S) as SKU's I want for my Shop.

#### Currently

As you can see A Shop is connected to the Products, and to the SKU's. But I have a feeling there's something wrong

> My shop_skus and shop_products are not connected, So there can be a mismatch between the products a shop has, and the sku's..

**How would I go about fixing that?**

Thank you for your time!

[image]

Comment: It is fine. And it isn't. It depends on your requirements. Do you allow a sku to be available for a shop that doesn't have the (related to this sku) product? If yes, everything is good.

Comment: I'm affraid not, The SKU's should always match the shop_products.. That's the big issue, thanks for your time

Comment: Then (one way to do this and the only one I know with DDL) is to drop the relationship from `shop_skus` to `shops` and make it from  `shop_skus` to `shop_products` instead. You will also need to add `product_id` in `shop_skus` for this to work and a few more minor modifications (2 of the FKs will be composite). See a similar problem: [Data inconsistency prohibition if a table refers to another via two many-to-many relationships](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138540/data-inconsistency-prohibition-if-a-table-refers-to-another-via-two-many-to-many/138541#138541) and my answer there.

Comment: Translation: (Realm=shop, Project=sku, Company=product)

Comment: I understand! I another thread someone proposed to add another model such as CarriedProduct, that would then replace the need for a diamond connection, what do you think about that?

Comment: The description (add another model) is a bit vague. I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Here's the answer on that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45423994/1731057

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: I didn't notice that this has been suggested already in comments by ypercube. So crediting him here.

Ultimately its up to you and your exact requirements. But here are following suggestions:

1. `SKU`s does not exists if `Products` does not exist. In other words, you cannot make a `SKU` as a standalone entity. The basic entity therefore is `Products`. And as a `Product` can have multiple `SKU`, make this relationship many to many.
2. So if you follow point 1, You can safely remove `shop_skus` relationship because now, a `shop` can select `products` via `shop_products` and as `products` are in many-many relationship with `SKU` you can enable `shop` to pick suitable `SKU` directly using suitable query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm wondering how I can still have a Shop select which SKU's of a product they want..

Comment: By using inner joins in your sql queries you can definitely do so.